# Prove the sequence $S_{n}$ $\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+n}$ is converge and have limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is my first time to prove problem in real analysis.
Please check it and point the mistake :)
$S_{n}$   $\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+n}$

$\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+n}$$-2< \epsilon $

$\frac{2n^{2}+1-2n^{2}+2n}{n^2+n}< \epsilon $

$\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}+n}< \epsilon $

$2n+1< \epsilon n^{2}+n\epsilon $

Because $n^{2}> n$ and $n^{2}\geq 2n$ for $n\geq 2$

It suffice to prove inequality holds,Limit is exist and sequence  converge by
defination $|S-s_{n}|\epsilon $ for every $n\geq N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|S_n-2|=\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{3n}{n^2}=\frac{3}{n}$. If $ \varepsilon >0$ we have for $n>\frac{3}{\varepsilon}:$

$|S_n-2|<\varepsilon$